Load a ttf font from the file system without embedding it as a resource
I have a Windows Forms application and I am trying to use a font from a file. Specifically it's the B612 font but I don't think it makes any difference.
I attempted to load it by using PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile(string) method. The font should be loaded properly as I don't receive any exceptions and I also iterate the font families of the collection and the font is there. Unfortunately, that has a problem: it doesn't work. The text is rendered with the fallback font.
I even tried to run this example from Microsoft. Without installing the font:

After installing the font:

Please note that in case the font files are under the expected directory. Otherwise the program wouldn't run.
The above is quite useless as I'd like the users to be able to drop their fonts directly to a directory as they might not have all administrative rights to install a font. Embedding the font as a resource won't help either as it removes flexibility.
Is it possible to load a font from a file without installing it?
I am trying this on .NET framework 4.8 Windows 10.0.19045
Addendum
Yes I know I didn't post any code. The code is in the example that I linked though. Granted, the internet has more dead links than alive ones. So here is a slightly modified version of the example where the screenshots are based on:
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FontFamily[] fontFamilies;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
            string[] ttfFiles = Directory.GetFiles("path to the fonts", "*.ttf");
            foreach (string ttfFile in ttfFiles)
            {
                privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(ttfFile);
            }

            fontFamilies = privateFontCollection.Families;
            Disposed += (_, _) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disposing");
                privateFontCollection.Dispose();
            };
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            PointF pointF = new PointF(10, 0);
            SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            int count = 0;

            count = fontFamilies.Length;

            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
            {
                string familyName = fontFamilies[j].Name;

                if (fontFamilies[j].IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
                {
                    Font regFont = new Font(
                        familyName,
                        16,
                        FontStyle.Regular,
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(
                        $"{familyName} {FontStyle.Regular}",
                        regFont,
                        solidBrush,
                        pointF);

                    pointF.Y += regFont.Height;
                }
                //so on and so forth for the rest of the styles

                pointF.Y += 10;
            }
        }
    }

I tried to keep the example as close to the original as possible. My changes were to remove the repetitive code for the rest of the font styles, remove the absurd comments stating the obvious and moved initialization and disposal to constructor.

We need to see your implementation context. What's the scope of the PFC? local? class? See this Q&A about this point. Try the solution there and get the fontArray by calling the File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); method. If it does not work either, then read the Remarks section.

Use TextRenderer.DrawText(), not Graphics.DrawString() in this context. In case this is what you're doing, you haven't posted any code

@Jimi No I'm not using TextRenderer.DrawText(). It has several disadvantages like for example that it can't render rotated text. Regardless, that wasn't the problem. The problem is that the example from MS (link in the question) is broken. I know, surprise, eh? I will post an answer later on although I'm tempted to delete the question altogether. I'm not sure if it provides any value or if anybody will care for that "ancient" technology. :(

@dr.null the code I used is there, in the "this example" link. I don't know if you had a look at it. Regardless, I updated the question as links have a tendency to disappear. You might also want to have a look at the answer I posted.

As an alternative, you can use the AddFontResourceA function to install font(s) for the current session. The font can be used by your and other applications as if it was installed font. Users don't need admin privilege since this does not require registry edit. The font is removed on restart/shutdown or by the RemoveFontResourceA. You also need to SendMessage the WM_FONTCHANGE msg afterward. See the Remarks.

PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection(); this must be a class field/property. Dispose of it in the OnFormClosed method.

The example is quite explicit:

The first argument passed to the Font constructor is the font family name (not a FontFamily object as is the case for other variations of the Font constructor)

(Emphasis mine)
Cool you think while you read it, it's exactly what I'm looking for! Until of course you run the example and you realize that reality is far from the example's claims.
Then dr.null pointed out in their comment "how about looking at this Q&A and see if it works". In that example, the FontFamily is passed directly; I tried it and of course it worked. Only this isn't what I'm looking for but I'll come to that later on.
I had a look in the FontFamily code and how it is created from a string. It calls GdipCreateFontFamilyFromName and the documentation for that method call as you can see isn't quite descriptive in how this FontFamily is created. The return result was 14 which maps to "font family not found". This means that either the example is wrong or there is a bug in GDI+. I would err towards the first case as in this answer it's pointed out that:

The PrivateFontCollection is probably not so easy to use in this context, as it doesn't make the fonts globally available in your application, but has to be used as constructor argument of Font.

Having to pass the reference to the FontFamily makes it completely impractical. I'm reading the files from a json config file. There I have the font family as a string and I rely on GDI+ "magic" to resolve the actual FontFamily object. Changing this invariant will have an impact on the application which might outweigh the benefit.
This leaves us with three options:

Tell the user to install the fonts manually.
Install some fonts considered "important" with InnoSetup during installation phase.
Bite the bullet and make the necessary changes to accommodate private fonts. This includes:

Create the font family list from the private font collection.
Pass this list to a "resolver" object that will use this list as a fallback if the font is not installed.
Modify json.net to use this resolver instead of directly creating a Font object from text.



I will not mark this as the correct answer yet as there might be something that I missed and I don't want to demotivate others from providing their own answer.

Not clear what you're trying to say here. You can use the FontFamily Name to build the Font. It's also preferred over passing the FontFamily object. The PrivateFontCollection provides the mapping (automatically). Get the unsafe PrivateFontCollection UnsafeLoadFontFamily() method (or the corresponding safe method) from here, then build the Font passing a string that contains the name of the Font family. This is a quite well tested method to render Fonts loaded from files or Project Resources

As mentioned before (unless you need to add unsupported transformations), TextRenderer.DrawText() performs (and looks) better than Graphics.DrawString(), in this context. Text of Controls is rendered using the former

@Jimi that's unfortunate that my point isn't clear. Did you run the example that I posted in the question? Did it work for you? Because it didn't work for me! And in any case, since this isn't a duplicate and if you have a working solution, I think that you can post it here. Thanks for your time reading and commenting nonetheless. PS: I tried TextRenderer.DrawText() with similar results.

In your example, the PrivateFontCollection is declared as a local variable in the Form's Constructor. You need to preserve it, storing it in a Field. Dispose of it in OnFormClosed(). Anyway, if you want to use Graphics.DrawString(), you have to pass the Name of the FontFamily. But I doubt you can use your Font without, at least temporarily, installing it, since it's not a real TrueType Font (GDI+ wise), it's a Type 1 conversion (now that I've checked it out). Using TextRenderer, you have to pass the FontFamily object to the Font constructor

@Jimi yes but hold on: it's captured in the Disposed closure. I'm quite sure that it's not disposed before its time. I confirmed it with the debugger. Finally, I don't understand the comment regarding the Type 1 conversion. Is this a problem with the font or with GDI+?

Not disposed doesn't mean it's functional. Also, you don't use a Lambda like that, in production, to subscribe to an event. It's more likely used for testing purposes (or posting answers here :). Use a Field and dispose of it as described -- The Font resource you linked is not entirely a True Type Font. It has True Type outlines, but OpenType layout. If you try to assign this Font (when it's installed) to a Control in the Designer, you most probably get an exception

@Jimi I don't want to disappoint you, but I just tried assigning the font (installed) to a TextBox and it worked. No exception. Text appears as expected. Tried with VS 17.8.4. BTW, in the second screenshot you can see the font rendering properly (when installed).

Did you assign this Font in the Designer (using the PropertyGrid in VS), or in code? As mentioned, Controls use TextRenderer (well, GDI) to render the Text, not GDI+

... or use the GraphicsPath to draw the text as a shape for better quality. You can then rotate/scale/flip/skew/whatever... the shape as you need.

@Jimi Yes, obviously.  Why would I mention VS version otherwise.

Then you're using a different Font. I got the package from Google Fonts, and as predicted cannot be assigned in the Designer. So we're probably talking about two different things. Possibly, make available the Fonts you actually have there

@Jimi I got the ttf font from the github repo
